# SAS principal component analysis help

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, sas

I have performed a principal component analysis on sas and have but my 15 variables into 4 factors so I have 4 new constructs. I now want to find out which of the original variables were important in the new constructs formed. How would I do this in SAS?